# SAPUI5 - Header and Footer for all applications

Tags: url, header, sapui5, radix

I'm pretty new to SAPUI5 and have a question:

Is it possible to have for example a base application with a custom Header and footer and to change only the content to the view of another application?

So basically I have for example 3 applications and one base application.
In the base application, there is only a page header and footer. I want to change the page content to the first view of one of the three application (for example based on a parameter, passed in URL).
With another parameter passed in URL, The content changes to the view of the second application.

In dynpros it was possible with subscreens, so a new "application" was inserted as a subscreen.

I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Its sounds like you are wanting a single page application with routing? SAPUI5 comes with routing that facilitates the change of the content.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe, sounds like the Page navivation concept in UI5, using the Router (as @Bernard said). More info [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d)

You can find a more specific example [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.navigation.17/preview) which does what you describe. You can reuse the code of this example app using the top right corner icon.

A different scenario is the navigation between different apps. In UI5/Fiori an app is the whole package with its own Component.js. So navigating from one app to another app means to load a new Component.js, start the execution from there, and rerender all the application controls, reset the models, and so on so forth. But this should not scare you if you really want to change the whole context. If you configure your apps correctly, you won't need to download the same libraries again when swtching between apps, because they will be cached. So the browser just needs to rerender (miliseconds for a header and footer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't think that you understood me correctly. With different applications I mean different BSP-applications submitted to the sap system. So basically one main application/bsp and therefor it dynamically loads the views und controllers of another bsp application, regarding to a parameter in the URL.

Comment: I think we are talking about the same concept but with different names. When you deploy a UI5 app in your NW system, it is saved in your BSP repository. The package you deploy has a Component.js file, where all the JS execution starts for this specific app. Now two scenarios: or you use the Fiori Launchpad as landing page (the Fiori Launchpad is the HTML document) and load the app you want from there; or you execute your apps in a standalone way (each app has its own index.html file).

Comment: So, I recommend you to use the Fiori Launchpad. It will load the main libraries once and then, it will render the difference UI5 apps deployed in your BSP repository starting the execution of each app in the Component.js file. Avoiding loading a new HTML document, and reusing the Fiori Launchpad Header and Footer.

Comment: Another 3rd option. Much more complicated. Is to build your own "Fiori Launchpad style" app. Which is only a shell with the controls you want and wherever you want you can use the sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer control, to load the different Component.js files of your apps wherever you want inside your "Fiori Launchpad Style" app.

Comment: Both, the official Fiori Launchpad and your own "Fiori Launchpad style" app can switch between apps just changing parameters in your URL (to be more specific, changing the hash route host:port/..../FioriLaunchpad.html/#LeaveRequest-approve )

Comment: Check out this link and the subsequent nodes: https://help.sap.com/viewer/17ae0e97e0fc424a9c368f350c0ba6bd/2.10/en-US/c82a9f6bc2454b46928315e45c0a5b7d.html

Comment: Okay, now I got it. Sorry, I've misunderstood you at first. Thank you very much! I look what I can do with those advices! :)